# CSS Image fit to parent using by max-width and max-height

Tags: html, css

I have some div's that each one contains an image, I don't want to make the images crop (cover or contain). but I need to fit them inside my `div`s via`max-height: 300px` and `max-width:100%`.

So I've tried so many things and none of them worked for my case.

Here is some attempts with their result: **(I'm using SCSS)**

My HTML:

```html
<div class="msg">
    <div class="msg-image">
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

1:

```css
.msg-image {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius:8px;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

[image]

> I've added `object-fit: contain;` to `img {...`, but the result was the same.
>
> By changing `max-width: 100%;` into `max-width: 300px;` the result was the same too.

---

2:

```css
.msg-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}
```

[image]

**So, How should I get rid of these unwanted gaps? The problem is I want to use max-width and max-height but seems like it's imposible with CSS only. If it's JS included solution, that is OK too**

Answer (score 0):

U can use bg-image to fix the problem.
But if u want to use img, set width and height on img ta and check result again.